# Write data to only first column of .csv file using SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

i wrote sql server table data to .csv file by using SSIS package. In flat file conncetion i've mentioned semi-colon as delimiter. Some of the values in my table are having commas(for example : CODE A,B,C) in .csv file CODE A is coming into 1st column and B is in 2nd vice-versa. now how can i keep all these values in a first column of .csv file with delimiter as ;

Comment: I seem to be missing the point, if you're delimiter is a semi-colon, commas will have no effect on it and the those values should be in the first column.  Perhaps you could show the data to better explain your problem?  Also, how are viewing the data to know that it is not delimited correctly?

Comment: value in table is : Security, Audit. In .csv it's coming as In colum1 : Security In cloumn2 :  Audit

Comment: No it's not.   Not if the .csv is delimited by semi-colons.   You are merely misinterpreting what you are seeing.

Comment: It should something like this "Security, Audit;Column2;Column3;..."

Comment: I'm using the Format : Delimited,Header row delimiter is ;  and Row delimiter {CR}{LF},Column Delimiter is ;

value Security, Audit. In between comma and audit we have one space.

Comment: That is the correct way to do it.   As I said, you DO have "Security, Audit" in column 1.   However, due to a mistake in the way you are looking at it, you only think that it is in two separate columns.  If the explanation in my answer isn't helping, please add a screenshot of what you are looking at that looks like Security is in column 2.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are opening your flat file in Excel, and opening it as a comma-separated file.

You need to specify to Excel when you open it that your file is delimited by semi-colons.   Then it will display correctly.